# Java: Class's type parameter extending its own subclass

Tags: java, abstract, type-parameter

could I get an explanation for what this method signature is doing?

```
AbstractRoad<T extends AbstractRoad.Builder<T>>
```

where there is a subclass called Builder in AbstractRoad's class.

So AbstractRoad has a type parameter..that extends it's own subclass to allow the class to do what exactly?

Comment: `AbstractRoad.Builder` is unlikely to be a subclass of `AbstractRoad`.  It is certainly a *nested* class, however, probably a static one.  We would need the code or documentation to do more than speculate about what is accomplished by using that class as a type parameter bound, though the names do lead to some general ideas.

Comment: An equally good question, by the way, would concern what is accomplished by nesting `AbstractRoad.Builder` in `AbstractRoad`, as I presume that you would not find its use as a bound so surprising if it were a top-level class instead of a nested one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the type parameter is an extension of the Builder... meaning it is expecting any type that is or extends the Builder Subclass

```
ArrayList<Inventory<T extends Item>>
```

This is an array list of inventories containing items or objects that extend item... i.e.

```
Public class Potion extends Item
```

would be a valid item in the inventory... T is a generics reference of essentially Object. Please see this link: [Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

Answer (score -1):

That is a [Generic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), which basically is a type that contains another type, or in this case, ***T***.

[ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), a **Generic**, stores objects of the type ***T***.

Generics work like normal classes, but with the differences just stated.

***Answer:*** Probally to use the object in some function.

***Note:*** Please post the source code, because it would allow me to give a better answer.

Comment: You did not answer the question that was asked.  If questions are unclear, post comments asking for clarification before guessing at an answer.  Answers are supposed to be useful to future visitors as well as the OP, so mere guesses are not usually helpful, as in this case.  See [answer]

Comment: I don't **have** the reputation to post a comment, Mr. @JimGarrison.